# ANOVA mixed design in R shows incorrect Df

Tags: r, mixed-model, degrees-of-freedom

I'm running mixed design ANOVA using R.  Somehow, I got incorrect values for the Df.   There are two factors: `time` (within subjects), and `task` (between subjects).  `Time` has four levels and `task` has three levels.  I expected to find Df 3 for `time` and Df 2 for `task`.  However, the ANOVA result I got showed 1 for the task Df under "Error:subject".

Why does this happen?

The dataset looks like this:

```
> data
subject  response  time  task  
1        1.0076499 time1 task1  
2        0.9939471 time1 task1  
3        0.9981924 time1 task1
4        0.9960073 time1 task1
5        1.0064204 time1 task1
6        0.9990992 time1 task1
7        0.9959636 time1 task1
8        0.9922857 time1 task2
9        1.0007059 time1 task2
10       0.9952433 time1 task2
11       0.9976965 time1 task2
12       0.9957487 time1 task2
13       1.0013376 time1 task2
14       0.9894985 time1 task2
15       1.0049207 time1 task3
16       0.9904670 time1 task3
17       1.0015606 time1 task3
18       1.0086701 time1 task3
19       0.9970305 time1 task3
20       0.9847713 time1 task3
21       0.9990247 time1 task3
1        1.0047615 time2 task1
2        0.9930625 time2 task1
3        1.0449758 time2 task1
4        1.0332383 time2 task1
5        1.0117085 time2 task1
6        0.9849849 time2 task1
7        0.9486615 time2 task1
8        0.9795459 time2 task2
9        0.9803583 time2 task2
```

The script I wrote is here:

```
data = read.csv("anova_data.csv", header=T)
anova_mixed = aov(response~(task*time)+Error(subject/time)+task, data)
summary(anova_mixed)
```

Then, the result:

```
Error: subject
     Df   Sum Sq  Mean Sq
task  1 0.001163 0.001163

Error: subject:time
     Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq
time  3 0.002001 0.0006671

Error: Within
          Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)   


task       2 0.005760 0.0028798   6.628 0.00234 **
time       3 0.000273 0.0000909   0.209 0.88976   
task:time  6 0.001679 0.0002798   0.644 0.69468   
Residuals 68 0.029544 0.0004345                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe your correct model is supposed to be

```
aov(response ~ task * time + Error(subject/time), data)
```

I just removed the additional "+task".

You can tell in your output there is a clear problem because your within subjects effect and your interaction should be grouped under the "Error: subject:time" section of the output.  If correcting the model input doesn't fix things then my guess is that you have an error in the data.  You have to have each time for each subject.  You can check this with:

```
table(data$subject, data$time)
```

If you're missing a cell here or have an unequal count then you have to drop that subject or, if you absolutely must, write a small dissertation on why you think it's OK to insert a fanciful value that allows you to keep them.

Also, you have to make sure that all categorical variables are factors, even subject.

Comment: Thank you John. I erased "+task". Then, in the result, under "Error: subject:time", it still says task Df is 1. Am I interpreting the anova table in a wrong way?  And sorry I didn't say the data example I put above is just a part of my data. I have equal number of subjects in each group (sn=7).

Comment: I doesn't matter how many subjects are in each group to get an appropriate output.  It matters that you have each subject at each time.  Did you look at the table output I suggested?  Furthermore, is the task really 'task1', 'task2', etc. or is it '1', '2', etc. in the task variable?

Comment: Yes. The subject number is the same in each time. I looked the table output too. There seems to be no error. The task variable is task1, task2...

Comment: That table output should actually be 1 in each cell.  If you try `table(data$task, data$time)` are the cell counts the same in each of the time values for each task?  What is the output of `str(data)`?

Comment: Yup, the table output was all 1. The outpu of str(data) was, `'data.frame': 84 obs. of  4 variables:`  `$ subject : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...`  `$ response: num  0.997 1.002 1.004 0.995 0.979 ...`  `$ time    : Factor w/ 4 levels "time1","time2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...`  `$ task    : Factor w/ 3 levels "task1","task2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...`

Comment: You need to make your subject variable a factor.

Comment: i.e. subject1, subject2, subject3... instead of 1,2,3,4 ...? It worked! Thank you!